# How to make docker CLI use specific network interface?

Tags: docker, macos, networking

My Mac mini has an Ethernet connection and a 4G LTE USB dongle. The latter has preference over the former. When I run things like `docker pull`, it takes forever since LTE speed is obviously lower than Ethernet, I go to network settings, change interface preference to make eth have higher priority, then I need to change it back. Is there a way to configure docker CLI, not containers, to always use `en0`?

Comment: Other CLI command (like 'git') also taking the 'wrong' network interface?

Comment: @BertC yeah they all do, it's not the wrong interface, it's just that I want to set a different interface for this specific app